# process.env.VARIABLENAME returns undefined

Tags: node.js, api, heroku, secret-key

I'm trying to access Heroku variables via `process.env.'variablename'`.
All variable that I've defined return as undefined.

I've tried `heroku config:set 'varname'='value'` which does come up when the following code is ran: `heroku config`.

I've also tried setting the variable through Heroku dashboard and I get the same result.

I'm positive I'm setting the variable correctly but accessing it is another story.

`console.log(process.env)` gets me:

```
{NODE_ENV: "production", PUBLIC_URL: ""}
   NODE_ENV: "production"
   PUBLIC_URL: ""
```

`console.log(process.env.var)` gets me:
  `undefined`

Technologies: React.js, Node.js, Express.js

Structure:

```
Root/
     client/
            src/
                components/
                           pages/locate.js
```

```
locate.js:
      let gkey;
      let tkey;
      let nkey;
      let wkey;
      if(process.env.NODE_ENV==='production'){
        gkey = process.env.GOOGLE;
        tkey = process.env.TIME;
        nkey = process.env.NEWS;
        wkey = process.env.WEATHER;
      }
```

typing in console : `heroku config -a appname`
returns:

```
=== appname Config Vars
GOOGLE:  KEYXXX
NEWS:    KEYXXX
TIME:    KEYXXX
WEATHER: KEYXXX
```

keep in mind this is the last method I resorted to. 
The values for keys were in a different file in an object.
Once that failed, I tried putting them in a function then the way Heroku recommended it:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

let s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.S3_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET
});
```

Comment: If that's front-end code (it looks like it is) it won't have access to environment variables at runtime. You need to compile those values into the front-end at build time. Do you have a `Procfile`? If so, what does it contain? What's in your `package.json`?

Comment: @Chris This is front end code and no, I don't have a Procfile.

Comment: And what's in your `package.json`? The `"scripts"` part is especially important. Please [edit] your question and add that.